# react - Alerts file leds to error in APP?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Very new to `react`. I am trying to learn by using a youtube tutorial.: link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fia-GGgHpK0&list=PLillGF-RfqbbRA-CIUxlxkUpbq0IFkX60&index=4

Traversy Media

Adding this information incase someone else goes looking. The answer is in the comments section of the video and I have posted it in comments as well.

I have the following code to show alerts:

```
// Alerts.js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert';

export class Alerts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.alert.show("It Works");
  }
  render() {
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}

export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

When I import this in `App.js` I start seeing errors.

If I comment out `<Alerts />` in the `render` then the page is visible again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong I have gone over the file 10 times, compared it with the tutorial.

```
import Alerts from './layout/Alerts';

// Alert Options
const alertOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    positon: "top center"
}

class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                    <Fragment>
                        <Header />
                        <Alerts />
                        <div className='container'>
                            <Dashboard />
                        </div>
                    </Fragment>
                </AlertProvider>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The full `App.js` imports:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';

import Header from './layout/Header';
import Dashboard from './leads/Dashboard';
import Alerts from './layout/Alerts';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

// Alert Options
const alertOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    positon: "top center"
}


class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                    <Fragment>
                        <Header />
                        <Alerts />
                        <div className='container'>
                            <Dashboard />
                        </div>
                    </Fragment>
                </AlertProvider>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Can you share the tutorial link?

Comment: Found the problem. The comments of the tutorial had the answer. Last line in `Alerts.js` is supposed to have a `()` right after the `withAlert` i.e.  `export default withAlert()(Alerts);`.